# Build a regexp for Oracle where last 4 values are 0-9 1-Z and not G I O S alphabets

Tags: java, oracle11g, regex-negation

The requirement to generate a Client id is `D<ABCDEFHJKL>XXXX` - Where `X` can be `0-9`, `A-Z` but not the letters `G`,`I`,`O`, or `S`.

I have created a regular expression which is generating a Client Id to be used in the database.

The regular expression is as follows.
`D[A-FHJ-L]{1}[^_:?GIOS-]{4}`

However, I am not sure how to enhance it that in the last 4 'X', it limits them with `0-9`, `A-Z` and not `G`, `I`, `O`, or `S`.

e.g. It will match `DAaaa_` or `DL00gA` and I want to exclude those.

Please suggest a better approach or a possible solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just write out all the characters it could be:

`D[A-FHJ-L][\dA-FHJ-NP-RT-Z]{4}`